# How do I make the username update in all message?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have everything saved in firestore in the tab Message, id is not assigned, can I make a listener that will find messages by email and dynamically change the data in username, each message?

Chat Page

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ChatPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChatPage> createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AuthProvider authProvider = Provider.of<AuthProvider>(context);
    final isLightTheme = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light;
    final AuthUser? authUser = authProvider.authUser;
    final TextEditingController message = new TextEditingController();
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    bool goodToGo = true;
    const snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text('Please wait 10 seconds before writing again'),
    );

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Community Chat'),
          centerTitle: false,
          actions: [
            if (authUser?.isAnonymous == false)
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () => Get.to(ProfilePage()),
                icon: Icon(Icons.manage_accounts),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: isLightTheme ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF181A20),
              child: ZCard(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 10),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  borderRadiusColor: Colors.transparent,
                  onTap: () =>
                      Get.to(() => PinsPage2(), fullscreenDialog: true),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(Icons.push_pin, size: 25, color: appColorYellow),
                      SizedBox(width: 16),
                      Text('New Pinned Message',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600)),
                      Spacer(),
                      Text('Read More',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 13,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: appColorYellow)),
                    ],
                  )),
            ),
            if (authProvider.authUser?.isAnonymous == false)
              SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 4),
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.71,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 3.00,
                      child: messages(
                        email: authUser?.username ?? '',
                        photo: authUser?.profileImage ?? '',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: TextFormField(
                            controller: message,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              filled: true,
                              fillColor: isLightTheme
                                  ? Color(0xFFF9F9F9)
                                  : Color(0xFF35383F),
                              hintText: 'Type your message',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFF3D10A)),
                              enabled: true,
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                  left: 14.0,
                                  right: 14.0,
                                  bottom: 12.0,
                                  top: 12.0),
                              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF35383F)),
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                              enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                                borderSide:
                                    new BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF35383F)),
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20),
                              ),
                            ),
                            validator: (value) {
                              return null;
                            },
                            onSaved: (value) {
                              message.text = value!;
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 8,
                        ),
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 20,
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3D10A),
                          child: IconButton(
                            highlightColor: Color(0xFFF3D10A),
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (!goodToGo) {
                                return;
                              }
                              if (goodToGo) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
                                    .showSnackBar(snackBar);
                              } // do your thing
                              goodToGo = false;
                              Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 7000),
                                  () {
                                goodToGo = true;
                              });
                              if (message.text.isNotEmpty) {
                                fs.collection('Messages').doc().set({
                                  'message': message.text.trim(),
                                  'time': DateTime.now(),
                                  'email': authUser?.username ?? '',
                                  'username': authUser?.email ?? '',
                                  'photo': authUser?.profileImage ?? '',
                                });

                                message.clear();
                              }
                            },
                            color: Color(0xFF292C31),
                            icon: Icon(
                              Icons.outbox,
                              size: 25,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 15,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            _buildSignIn()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Message

```
class messages extends StatefulWidget {
  String email;
  String photo;
  messages({
    required this.email,
    required this.photo,
  });

  @override
  _messagesState createState() => _messagesState(
        email: email,
        photo: photo,
      );
}

class _messagesState extends State<messages> {
  String email;
  String photo;
  _messagesState({
    required this.email,
    required this.photo,
  });

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }



  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _messageStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('Messages')
      .orderBy('time')
      .snapshots();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isLightTheme = Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light;
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: _messageStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("something is wrong");
        }
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        }

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
          physics: ScrollPhysics(),
          shrinkWrap: true,
          primary: true,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            QueryDocumentSnapshot qs = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
            Timestamp t = qs['time'];
            DateTime d = t.toDate();
            print(d.toString());
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, bottom: 8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: email == qs['email']
                    ? CrossAxisAlignment.end
                    : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SwipeTo(
                    onRightSwipe: () {
                      print('Callback from Swipe To Right');
                    },
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 400,
                      child: ListTile(
                        tileColor:
                            isLightTheme ? appColorCardLight : appColorCardDark,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          side: BorderSide(
                            color: isLightTheme
                                ? appColorCardBorderLight
                                : appColorCardBorderDark,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        leading: CircleAvatar(
                          backgroundImage: NetworkImage(qs['photo']),
                        ),
                        title: Text(
                          qs['email'].isEmpty ? qs['username'] : qs['email'],
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 15,
                            color: Color(0xFFF3D10A),
                          ),
                        ),
                        subtitle: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              width: 200,
                              child: Text(
                                qs['message'],
                                softWrap: true,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.reply_all,
                              size: 25,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              d.hour.toString() + ":" + d.minute.toString(),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```